# http requests in stenciljs

Tags: xmlhttprequest, axios, stenciljs

How can I make http requests (GET / POST / PUT / DELETE) in StencilJS?

I tried using axios as follows: Did `npm install axios --save` and in the stencil component `import axios from 'axios';`. As soon as I call `axios.get(...)`I get the following error message:

---

[ ERROR ]  bundling: node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js, line: 4

A module cannot import itself

L3:  var utils = require('./../utils');

L4:  var settle = require('./../core/settle');

L5:  var buildURL = require('./../helpers/buildURL');

---

I understand it might have to do with this issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/98

However, any recommendations on how to get html requests work within a stencil component?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can use the `fetch` API. It is browser native and does therefore not need an import. StencilJS also has a polyfill for it, so it works everywhere.

Thanks to @insanicae for pointing me to it.

> Example:

```
import { Component, State } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'app-profile',
  styleUrl: 'app-profile.css'
})
export class AppProfile {
  @State() name: string;

  componentWillLoad() {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/ErvinLlojku')
      .then((response: Response) => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.name = response['name'];
      });
  }

  render() {
    return [
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar color="primary">
          <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button defaultHref="/" />
          </ion-buttons>
          <ion-title>Profile: {this.name}</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>,

      <ion-content padding>
        <p>My name is {this.name}.</p>

      </ion-content>
    ];
  }
}
```

Consult official docs of fetch for more. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of how to implement this? Thanks!!

Comment: @mtaff i provided some example of usage for you. Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can even use my [component](https://github.com/Fdom92/stencil-fetch) to use Fetch API, just drop the URL and listen for the OK or KO event.

Comment: I tried your component and  got the response status but not sure how to take the response from it.

Comment: I see that you can only listen to it but don’t see a way to get the data from it.

Comment: well, the data is inside the event on the listener

Comment: Is this really the way we should implement utils/services/factories etc? 
By placing a (Stencil-compiled) Custom Element on the DOM, getting it using `document.querySelector(..)` and calling a `@Method`-annotated function?

Comment: @DJ_HOEK No. I don't see any benefit at all in this approach instead of calling `fetch` directly in your code.