# Stenciljs unit testing getting error : ReferenceError XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, stenciljs

I'm trying to create units test for my stencil js component, in the compnentWillLoad() method it will do an HTTP request (using rxjs).when I'm run the test getting error  **ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined**.But when removing the HTTP request from the componentWillLoad() method test passed.
My test as below,

```
it('should render my component', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyComponent],
      html: `<my-component></my-component>`,
    });
    expect(page.root).toEqualHtml(`<my-component></my-component>`);
  });
```

I'm getting error  **ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XHR testing in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584773/xhr-testing-in-jest)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar troubles with `Stencil`, `Jest` and `XMLHttpRequest`.

First, make sure you call

```
new window.XMLHttpRequest()
```

instead of simply calling

```
new XMLHttpRequest()
```

This [seems to be neccessary when using jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1426) and may already resolve your issue.

It didn't resolve mine though, since I wanted to make sure there are no real API calls going on. So I tried to mock `XMLHttpRequest`. However, I ran into other issues while building the mock and finally decided to refactor my code to use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of `XMLHttpRequest` which [seems to be better supported by Stencil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47282188/1165421).

You can easily mock `fetch` using jest

```
export function mockFetch(status, body, statusText?) {
  // @ts-ignore
  global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      status: status,
      statusText: statusText,
      text: () => Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify(body)),
      json: () => Promise.resolve(body),
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`XMLHttpRequest` is indeed not defined in the virtual DOM context that is created when you use `newSpecPage`.

The best solution for you is probably to write this as an E2E test instead, using `newE2EPage`, which is more suited for complete end-to-end testing because it runs in a real browser context where `XMLHttpRequest` will be available.

```js
it('should render', async () => {
  const page = await newE2EPage({ html: '<my-component></my-component>' });

  const myComponent = page.find('my-component');

  expect(myComponent).toHaveClass('hydrated');
});
```

"Spec Page" testing is rather meant for unit testing components that work stand-alone. If your goal is to actually unit-test your component and you just want to be able to instantiate your component but you don't actually need the request to succeed for testing, then you can also use the `Build` context from Stencil:

```js
import { Build, ... } from '@stencil/core';

export class MyComponent {
  componentWillLoad() {
    if (!Build.isTesting) {
      // make the request
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I think that's a little over the top. I don't want to bootstrap a complete e2e setup just to execute a unit test.

Comment: Not sure what there is to bootstrap but anyway IMO, for the OP's case it sounds less over the top to run an e2e test than to refactor their code to use `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.